# Textmate - render different types of code in different highlighting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, syntax-highlighting, textmate

I have an `.html.erb` document that has a javascript section at the bottom. Ordinarily Textmate recognizes the `<script>` tag and converts everything inside to its Javascript(Rails) format.

To cut down on `<script>` tags I enclosed this js code in:

```
# lots of html.erb above...

<% content_for :footer_js do %>
lots of javascript
<% end %>
```

How can I tell Textmate to show the correct highlighting for this Javascript(Rails) section of code?

Answer (score 1):

https://gist.github.com/1018085/1049531ca917fa71141dc5e3b7bd7016adaef37d Shows how to do it. You'll just need to change the regex that matches :inline_js to your :footer_js

Answer (score 0):

I have also looked for this answer, but after much research, I'm not sure it's possible unless you edit a bundle to add this functionality.